# What is the difference between libfreerdp-dev and freerdp-x11?

Tags: rdp

What is the difference between `libfreerdp-dev` and `freerdp-x11`?

Does installing `libfreerdp-dev` also install RDP server? What is `xrdp`?

I need to install RDP server but don't know which is what.

Answer (score 1):

[`libfreerdp-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libfreerdp-dev) (as the `dev` indicates) is for development - writing code that makes use of [the FreeRDP library](http://www.freerdp.com/api). [`freerdp-x11`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/freerdp-x11) is an RDP client (that is built on the FreeRDP library).

> Does installing `libfreerdp-dev` also install RDP server?

No.

> What is `xrdp`?

[`xrdp`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xrdp) is an RDP server. If you want to install an RDP server, this is one.

---

In case you don't know what a package is for, run `apt-cache show <package-name>`, and read the `Description`. For example:

```
$ apt-cache show libfreerdp-dev xrdp
Package: libfreerdp-dev
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 329
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Mike Gabriel <sunweaver@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: freerdp
Version: 1.0.2-2ubuntu1
Depends: libfreerdp1 (= 1.0.2-2ubuntu1), libfreerdp-plugins-standard (= 1.0.2-2ubuntu1)
Filename: pool/main/f/freerdp/libfreerdp-dev_1.0.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 52978
MD5sum: d6c5168d4b415a5346fc2708667e81a2
SHA1: ebbff4b0d9804194f22500f9ec2b98745328c642
SHA256: fbf8ad8ef6a416fc14b85fa73e1a76bb96eb77bd896086d78111ff16cab1cf6b
Description: RDP client for Windows Terminal Services (development)
Description-md5: a097a02e403e05e19dd894fd2672c390
Homepage: http://www.freerdp.com/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m

Package: xrdp
Priority: optional
Section: universe/net
Installed-Size: 1565
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Vincent Bernat <bernat@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.6.0-1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libx11-6, libxfixes3, adduser
Recommends: vnc4server | tightvncserver | vnc-server
Filename: pool/universe/x/xrdp/xrdp_0.6.0-1_amd64.deb
Size: 277112
MD5sum: 9e5534c9bfaae97b7955508a9d679d73
SHA1: 401725647f4eef969fba6cdc630dc5ef66481c32
SHA256: 272d93eb4d1256a0a4cb4eac75266f882da52e258565b349f9107b001f0cbb82
Description: Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server
Description-md5: b98c1889e17be6136503794b3491891b
Homepage: http://xrdp.sourceforge.net
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

The `Descriptions` for `libfreerdp-dev` reads:

```
RDP client for Windows Terminal Services (development)
```

And that of `xrdp`:

```
Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server
```

Comment: thanks, its clear now. one thing more- do you perhaps know what this error comes from xrdp_mm_process_login_response:login failed ? do i need to install anything more ? i am logging from win7 to ubuntu(rdp)