# what is the difference between freerdp and xrdp?

Tags: xrdp

i am new to ubuntu and rdp.

i need to install rdp on ubuntu. what is the difference between freerdp and xrdp? are these two the same or equivalent? does installing xrdp also install freerdp? I have installed xrdp but now want freerdp, how to get freerdp?

thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between libfreerdp-dev and freerdp-x11?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/717097/what-is-the-difference-between-libfreerdp-dev-and-freerdp-x11)

Answer (score 8):

FreeRDP is an implementation of the remote desktop protocol (http://www.freerdp.com/) to connect to RDP-Servers. The software remmina seems to use it.

XRDP is an server software to allow other clients connect to the system using a rdp client.